# Copy Item Action not available in share point 2013 workflows

Tags: designer-workflow

I want to copy list item to other list , but in SharePoint Designer 2013 that particular (copy Item) Action is not available. What should i Do?

Answer (score 0):

To copy list item, you can create a workflow with 2010 platform.
Following link might help you 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6a203fe4-6bb2-41a8-a1ed-ff4feed7a2d9/why-is-there-no-copy-list-item-workflow-action-in-sharepoint-designer-2013-?forum=sharepointcustomization